# Replace all control characters in a range of line with awk

Tags: bash, awk

I got a file with several lines. Some of these lines contain LFs `(0x0A)` and CRs `(0x0D)`, which I want to get removed. The point is, that I want to replace them with SPACE them only in a range of characters of every line, eg in a File:

```
30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 **0D 0A** 30 30 0A; 0000000000..00
30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 **0D 0A** 30 30 30 30 0A; 00000000..0000
```

I want to remove 0d, 0a from position 0 to 12 in every line of the file.

I got

```
awk '{l=substr($0,1,12);r=substr($0,13);gsub(/\x00-\1F/," ",l);print l r}' ${f} > ${f}.noLF
```

but this seems not to work. I guess substr stops at the first 0x0d.
Is there another solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk '/\r$/ && length < 13 {sub(/\r$/,""); printf "%s  ", $0; next} {print}' file
```

Comment: My definition of a line seperator is every 0A "outside" of position 13. Thats why I want to limit the replacements to a certain range (position 1-12).

Comment: How long should each line be?

Comment: There's no fix length :-( Every line can size can be different, but non is smaller then 15 characters

Answer (score 0):

Here is something ugly that may work!

Save it as `go`

```
#!/bin/bash
while :
do
    # Read 13 bytes from stdin, and replace carriage returns and linefeeds with spaces
    dd bs=13 count=1 2>/dev/null | tr '\r\n' '  '

    # Break out of loop if dd was not successful
    [ ${PIPESTATUS[0]} -ne 0 ] && break

    # Get rest of conventional line, breaking out of loop if EOF
    read rest || break
    echo $rest
done
```

It reads 13 bytes from your file and removes all carriage returns and linefeeds. Then it reads the rest of the conventional *line* and outputs that.

Use it like this:

```
chmod +x go
./go < yourfile
```

Example:

```
more file
q
wertyuiopqwertyuiop
qwerty
uiopqwertyuiop

./go < file
q wertyuiopqwertyuiop
qwerty uiopqwertyuiop
```

**EDITED TO MATCH FURTHER QUESTIONS**

```
#!/bin/bash
while :
do
    # Read 13 bytes from stdin, and replace carriage returns and linefeeds with spaces
    first13=$(dd bs=13 count=1 2>/dev/null)
    ddexitstatus=$?

    if [ echo $first13 | grep -q "^KT" ]; then
       echo $first13
    else
       echo $first13 | tr '\r\n' '  '
    fi   

    # Break out of loop if dd was not successful
    [ $ddexitstatus -ne 0 ] && break

    # Get rest of conventional line, breaking out of loop if EOF
    read rest || break
    echo $rest
done
```

Comment: You probably want `tr '\r\n' '  '` instead of `tr -d '\r\n'`

Comment: @glennjackman Yes, thank you! I was focussing on the OP's  wanting "removed" rather than `replacing`.

Comment: make sure you have 2 spaces in the last arg for tr

Comment: Is there a possibility to add a condition, such as "if the line starts with "KT"" or something?

Comment: Do you mean a) only remove CRLF on lines starting with KT? Or b) only output lines starting with KT and no others? Or something else?

Comment: Sorry, didn't express clearly. I mean a). Just do the replacement on lines starting with "KT", but the output must contain all lines (modified and non-modified).

Comment: I have updated my answer, but from an iPad with no way to check - hopefully it will get you close enough to work out any errors.